# nodejs javascripts window/images without use of html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, 2d, rendering

This is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow.

Hi I am wabsol, i am using and learning nodejs.

I would want to create a window and/or draw an image in javascript without the use of html and its canvas element.

I want to use a image that can be transparant for example .png.

I do not know if this is possible or not.

note: my native language is not English

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do exactly? A web application? A desktop application? 
Did you know that *nodejs* is a javascript runtime that is principally use for backend application?

I think that what you want is a rendering engine for the canvas element.

[There is a list on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=html5+rendering+engine&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: a desktop application is what i want to achieve

Comment: i want to achieve this [link](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/empty_window.jpg)

Comment: i will explain better, i want to display multiple pictures on the user his or her screen without having a background, for example something like this [link](http://img00.deviantart.net/8543/i/2011/340/c/0/desktop_ponies_at_school_by_garyd12-d4icixc.png)

Comment: also i would want to achieve this without the use of html and its canvas element

Comment: You could use [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to create cross platform desktop apps with web technologies: **HTML**, **CSS**, **JS**.

Comment: I am using nodejs and i am researching how to make a plugin for nodejs that allows me to render images